# Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, undirected-graph, cycle-detection

[image: The graph in question]

I have this undirected and weighted graph in the above link and I just cannot detect how many cycles are there. I have tried BFS, DFS and Set disjoint method but all of them just goes wrong somewhere while calculating. I can do the code. The problem arises when I try to do it in pen and paper. Is there any algorithm/method by which I can efficiently calculate the no. of cycles?

I have tried BFS, DFS and Set Disjoint methods.

Comment: Do you need to do this for this _specific_ graph, or more generally? Is the graph that you'll be working with always planar? For a planar graph like this one, you can identify cycles with the regions they enclose, and any region corresponds to a subset of the 6 faces that occur in the graph. There are 2^6=64 such subsets, and it's easy to enumerate them all and determine which ones come from cycles. (I believe that the answer for this particular graph is 37 - there are 4 * 7 = 28 that include the central face DHFGJ and 9 that don't.)

Comment: For algorithmic purposes, what's the data structure you're using for the graph (and what programming language)?

Comment: What is the expected result for the example graph?

Comment: As people have pointed out - it all depends on how you define what a "different cycle" is.  This definition will depend on what the purpose is for doing this.  Since you have not told us why you want to do this ... your question as stated cannot be answered.

Comment: @trincot i can't figure that out. Thats the issue.

Comment: @ravenspoint For my purpose, a cycle here would only be considered a cycle if you start from a node and come back at that exact node (without backtracking of course).

Comment: If you don't know what you need to get as output, then how can you validate any answer here as correct or not correct? Moving on...

Comment: Are GFE, FEG, EGF three 'different' cycles or are they just different representations of one cycle?  How about GFG and FGF?  You must clarify your question by editing it to sort out the ambiguities, then request it to be re-opened so we can answer it.

Comment: You should also tell us what the purpose of this is.  That is the only way we can help you along in the correct direction.

Comment: It might help us if you gave an example with a simpler graph. For example, suppose we keep the vertices A, B, D, G and J and the edges joining them, and throw away everything else. So the graph now looks like a triangle and a quadrilateral, sharing an edge (A–J) between them. How many cycles would you consider that that graph has, and what are they?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you first need to determine what the "amount of cycles" is.
If I unterstand correctly, that is "amount of different cycles in  the graph"

Then you need to define what's "different cycles" is.
Cycles are different if their normalized form is different.
The normalized form I choose is "starts with the lowest node, second node is lesser then last"
e.g. `ABDJ` is the normalized form for `ABDJ`, `ABJD`, `BJDA` and `BADJ`

Then all you need is the size of set of unique normalized cycle paths

---

The optimized algorithm would be DFS with disabling the first node after all cycles through this node were already found. This also forces each cycle to appear exactly twice (in two directions). This redeces the difficulty from `O(N!)` to `O( (N-1)! )`